# How do I determine "Big-oh" time complexity given an excel sheet showing various input size values VS their corresponding run time values

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I have been given a list of input sizes and their corresponding runtime values for a given algorithm A. How should I go about computing the "Big-oh" time complexity of algorithm A given these values?

Answer (score 1):

Try playing around with the numbers and see if they approximately fit one of the "standard" complexity functions, e.g. `n`, `n^2`, `n^3`, `2^n`, `log(n)`.

For example, if the ratio between value and input is nearly constant, it's likely `O(n)`. If the ratio between value and input grows linearly (or doubling the input quadruples the value etc.), it is `O(n^2)`. If it grows quadratically, it's `O(n^3)`. If adding a constant to the input results in multiplicative change in its value, it's exponential. And if it's the reverse relationship, it's `log(n)`.
If it's just slightly but consistently growing more quickly than a line, it's probably `O(n log(n))`.

You can also plot the graph of your values (input numbers vs runtime values) in Excel and overlay it with the graph of the function you guessed may fit, and then try to tweak the parameters (e.g. for `O(n^2)`, plot a graph of `a*x^2 + b`, and tweak `a` and `b`).

To make it more precise (e.g. to calculate the uncertainty), you could apply regression analysis (search for  *non-linear regression analysis in Excel*).